# Re-execute js on back without reloading the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Is there a way to re-execute JS without refreshing a page?

Say if I have a parent page and an inside page. When the inside page gets called, it gets called via ajax, replacing the content of the parent page. When user clicks back, I would like to navigate them back to the parent page without having to reload the page. But, the parent page UI relies on javascript so after they click back, I would like to re-execute the parent page's javascript. Is this possible?

**Edit:** Here is some code. I wrap my code in a function but where and how would you call this function?

```
function executeGlobJs() {
   alert("js reload success");
}
```

Comment: Could you give us some code?

Comment: You want the whole JS (in included files as well) on the page or just a part of it?

Comment: Use the Functions, Luke =)

Comment: Probably all js. Because I have js plugins in a separate file that I would need to re-execute as well.

Comment: I'm currently trying the approach of wrapping my js in a function. But where & how would I call that function to trigger it when user navigates back? Please show code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the html5 history-api:

In your `click`-handler you'll call the `pushState`-method, stat stores the current state for later reuse:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.link', function () {
  // some ajax magic here to load the page content
  // plus something that replaces the content...  

  // execute your custom javascript stuff that should be called again
  executeGlobJs()

  // replace the browser-url to the new url
  // maybe a link where the user has clicked
  history.pushState(data, title, url);
})
```

...later if the user browses back:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function () {
  // the user has navigated back,
  // load the content again (either via ajax or from an cache-object)
  // execute your custom stuff here...
  executeGlobJs()
})
```

This is a pretty simple example and of course not perfect!
You should read more about it here:

- https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

For the ajax and DOM-related parts, you should need to learn a bit about jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. (It's all about the magic dollar sign)

Another option would be the `hashchange`-event, if you've to support older browsers...

Comment: hows the browser/device support for this solution?

Comment: There's a site called "caniuse" to search for this kind of questions ;) http://caniuse.com/#search=history

Comment: Still trying the different approaches. I will mark an answer complete when I finish. Thank you.

Comment: @user1389082 Ok, if you have any quedtions, don't be shy to ask here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate all your javascript into a function, and call this function on page load.
And eventually this will give you control of re-executing entire javascript without reloading the page.

This is common practise when you use any concat utility (eg. Gulp)

Comment: Where/how would I call the function? As inline js in my body?

Comment: Calling function can be on any event, Some of which I can think of are below
- On page load as body onload event
- On any button click where you want to get your previous page
- On mouse Click or Mouse hover 
Below is the list of events which can be used
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload the script files as if it would be on a page reload, habe a look at [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

For all other script functions needed, just create a wrapper function as @s4n989 and @Rudolf Manusadzhyan wrote it. Then execute that function when you need to reinit your page.

Comment: Where/how would I call the function? As inline js in my body?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem I don't use jquery.
I don't have a solution yet. I think that your problem is that it doesn't read all the document.getelements after you add content, so my idea is to put all the element declarations in a function. And than after the ajax call ends to call the function to get all the elements again.

So it might be something like that

```
Func getElems(){
    const elem= document.getelementsby...
    Const elem.....


At the end of the js file make a call for 
the function 
getelems()

And than at the end of the event of the 
ajax call. Just call the function again.
```

Sorry that is something that comes to my mind on the fly while reading and thinking on the problem i have too:).

Hope it helped I will try it too when I will be on the computer :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for a function called

```
.preventDefault();
```

Here's a link to better explain what it does - https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Hope this helps!

---

#### EDIT:

By the way, if you want to execute the JS on back you can wrap the script inside of

```
$('.your-div').on('load', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //your JavaScript goes here
}
```